# Devide $price into partial payment (output issues over 1000 in amount)

Tags: php, html, klarna

Good Evening ppl.

Ive finished all coding for andvertising where I will show possible ways for customer to divide payment into 6 months. Everythings good, except I have issues with the output for new price when amount is more than 1000, I guess its because of the space?! in 1 000...?

This is the code: 
`Pay over 6 months: <?php if ($price_calculate['price_wo_discount']>0) echo round( ($price_calculate['price_wo_discount'])*0.16); ?>`

Comment: do remove the space

Comment: The output atm. when price is;
Old price: Price 762,-
New output: Pay over 6 months: 121,-
Old price: Price 1001,-
New output: Pay over 6 months: 0,-

Comment: ***Do not use floating point numbers for handling currency, you will literally lose money.*** Use a proper library designed to handle currency, eg: https://packagist.org/packages/moneyphp/money

Comment: at a minimum look at `bcmath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to do something like this in PHP,

```
echo round( '1 000' * 0.16);
```

You would get `Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in ...`. This is because PHP cannot safely cast the string into appropriate numeric value. It magically casts the string to `0` and throws a notice. That's why you get `0` output.

Ideally you need to remove all spaces and commas from you numeric string, then possibly use the [is_numeric](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) function to determine if your string is actually numeric, then do `round`.

Also implicit casting in you `if ($price_calculate['price_wo_discount'] > 0` block might lead to some side effects. Consider this in PHP:

```
var_dump('1 is number' > 0); //outputs true
```

My advice: use **value objects** to validate your input first.